# Bonita utility with alfresco

Tags: alfresco, bonita

I'm new to Bonita and Alfresco and I want to know the relation between these two plateforms (why I need Bonita while using alfresco)

Comment: did you see this link http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/5x/bos-56/connectivity/connectors-bonita-open-solution/alfresco

Comment: You do not need Bonita while using alfresco !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alfresco is a Open source Enterprise Content Management System, developed using JAVA technology for Microsoft Windows and UNIX like operating system. It allows managing different type of content like simple office documents, images, photographs, engineering drawings and even large audio/video files.

Document management:  Can store and track all type of documents.

Web content management:  Allow users with little knowledge of web programming languages or markup languages to create and manage website content with relative ease

Image management:  Can capture, store and reprint images.

Workflow: In Alfresco a workflow is a sequence of connected tasks applied to a document or other item of content. Each task can be performed by a person, a group, or automatically. There are a number of tools you get to design, execute, and monitor your workflows.

Content repository: The content repository is comparable to a database, except that it holds more than data. The binary streams of content are stored in the repository and the associated full-text indexes are maintained by the Lucene indexes.

You can found more description of BONITA using this link [http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/6.x-7.2/bonita-bpm-overview](http://BONITA%20DOC)

you can find tutorial on github for Bonita-connector-alfresco
https://github.com/bonitasoft/bonita-connector-alfresco

Answer (score 1):

Bonita is an open source BPM platform, and is not a part of Alfresco in any way.

If you want BPM capabilities you could use it, but have a look at Activiti first (BPM platform which is bundled with Alfresco) to determine if you really need it.

You could also check out Flowable (done by former Activiti guys), Camunda (which started as an earlier Activiti) fork and JBPM.